# Unable to copy file from remote machine in a remote post-build event with Visual C++ for Linux Development

Tags: linux, visual-c++, visual-studio-2017, post-build-event

I'm developing to Linux OS using Visual Studio 2017 (version 15.7.1) with Visual C++ for Linux Development version 1.0.9

As part of the build procedure, I'm moving the source files to the remote Linux machine (Ubuntu 16.04) and building it - so far so good.

As the final step of this procedure, I wish to copy "back" one file (a tar.gz file) back to my local machine (Windows 10 64 bit).

I have tried:

`$(RemoteProjectDir)/path/to/myfile.tar.gz:=$(SolutionDir)..\..\path\to\destination\folder\`

Under: Project --> Properties --> Remote Post-build event --> Additional Files To Copy

But with no successes.

Is it possible at all ? If so - what am I missing here ?

Appreciate your assistance !!

Thanks,

Guy.